# Can't route properly Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, angular-ui-router, spark-java

Trying make REST API for TodoApp written Angular, set routes for ADD, UPDATE, GET ALL, but stuck on DELETE method. 
My angular controller:

```
angular.module('todoListApp')
.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope, Todo) {
  $scope.deleteTodo = function(todo, index) {
    $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
    todo.$delete();
    console.log("<<" + todo.name + ">> deleted.");
 };
```

Angular service:

```
angular.module('todoListApp')
.factory('Todo', function($resource){
  return $resource('/todos/', {id: '@id'}, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    },
    save: {
      method: 'POST'
    },
    delete: {
      method: 'DELETE',
      params: {id: '@id'}
    }

  });
});
```

My Spark controllers:

```
    delete("/todos", "application/json", (req, res) -> {
        Todo todo = gson.fromJson(req.body(), Todo.class);
        if (todo == null) throw new ApiError(404, "Could not find todo.");
        todoDao.delete(todo);
        return todo;
    }, gson::toJson);

    delete("/todos/:id", "application/json", (req, res) -> {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(req.params("id"));
        Todo todo = gson.fromJson(req.body(), Todo.class);
        if (todo == null) throw new ApiError(404, "Could not find todo.");
        todoDao.delete(todo);
        return todo;
    }, gson::toJson);
```

When clicking DELETE button (ng-click="deleteTodo(todo, $index)") first controller invoked, but not second. I made two just for debugging.
Error message is:

```
angular.js:10661 DELETE http://localhost:4567/todos?id=3 404 (Not Found)
```

where I can see right id parameter, but why controller doesnt catch it?

Comment: delete("/todos/:id", "application/json", (req, res) -> {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(req.params("id"));
            Todo todo = gson.fromJson(req.body(), Todo.class);
            if (todo == null) throw new ApiError(404, "Could not find todo.");
            todoDao.delete(todo);
            return todo;
        }, gson::toJson);

Comment: Spark controllers in question body = Java controller for this url, or what you mean?

Comment: sorry, I got confused. I will delete my comment. (you can delete yours too)

Answer (score 0):

[$Resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage)

> Given a template /path/:verb and parameter {verb:'greet',
>   salutation:'Hello'} results in URL /path/greet?salutation=Hello

But your API expects /parameter

Answer (score 0):

Error was in angular .factory code, there must be

```
angular.module('todoListApp')
.factory('Todo', function($resource){
  return $resource('/todos/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    },
    save: {
      method: 'POST'
    },
    delete: {
      method: 'DELETE',
      params: {id: '@id'}
    }

  });
});
```

lost ':id' in return $resourse line.